# jQuery prop() and Google Closure Compiler

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-closure-compiler

I'm using google closure compiler and I've been getting a warming that I don't understand. I need to test if a radio button is checked or not so I have the following code:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @output_file_name default.js
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @externs_url http://closure-compiler.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/contrib/externs/jquery-1.8.js
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

function test() {

  var TheBool = $('#SomeElement').prop('checked');

  if (TheBool === true) {
     alert('checked');
   }
}
```

I'm getting a warning that says that it's a condition that always evaluates to false, even though I know that's not the case.

[image]

You can try this out at http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home and copy-paste the code as I have it (make sure to check "Optimization : Advanced")

How do I make this warning go away?

Comment: I don't get any warnings or errors...

Comment: @Ian: that's because you didn't set the compilation mode to "Advanced".

Comment: You are quite right. Sorry about that :)

Comment: If you remove the `=== true`, the warning goes away for me. Maybe because it's not necessary to compare to a boolean, when the result is a boolean and is used as a condition anyway

Comment: @Ian: the whole point of the bool is to test if the radio button is checked or not, hence I need the true/false test

Comment: No you **don't** need to check. If you use `if (anything)`, the `anything` is evaluated as a boolean. Anyways, the **result** of `.prop()` is a **boolean**, so it's **not necessary** to have `=== true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the [`externs` file](http://closure-compiler.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/contrib/externs/jquery-1.8.js)  provided by Google.

They incorrectly declare `jQuery.prototype.prop` as returning *either* a string or jQuery, and ignore the fact it can return a Boolean;

```
/**
 * @param {(string|Object.<string,*>)} arg1
 * @param {(string|number|boolean|function(number,String))=} arg2
 * @return {(string|!jQuery)}
 */
jQuery.prototype.prop = function(arg1, arg2) {};
```

... when it should be;

```
/**
 * @param {(string|Object.<string,*>)} arg1
 * @param {(string|number|boolean|function(number,String))=} arg2
 * @return {(string|boolean|!jQuery)}
 */
jQuery.prototype.prop = function(arg1, arg2) {};
```

I fixed this and [uploaded it](http://files.mattlunn.me.uk/permanent/jquery-1.8.js), and when using that declaration of externs, your problem is fixed;

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @output_file_name default.js
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @externs_url http://files.mattlunn.me.uk/permanent/jquery-1.8.js
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

function test() {

  var TheBool = $('#SomeElement').prop('checked');

  if (TheBool === true) {
     alert('checked');
   }

}
```

You'll be able to *bypass* this by not checking directly for `=== true`; just `if (TheBool)` will be enough.

---

FWIW, this has been [reported](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/detail?id=987) on their issues page, and a patch submitted.

Comment: Ok, that's really good to know. May be someone in charge of the externs can fix it. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

`prop` returns a boolean value. So there's no need to check if it `=== true`. Just use:

```
if (TheBool) {
    alert('checked');
}
```

To make it more understandable when reading, try:

```
var elementIsChecked = $('#SomeElement').prop('checked');
// `elementIsChecked` is either true or false

if (elementIsChecked) { // `elementIsChecked` is coerced into a boolean, but it already is, so it doesn't matter
    alert('checked');
}
```

and maybe you'll understand why it's not necessary in the first place.

Expressions used in `if ()` are evaluated as true or false, whether or not their result is true or false. It just happens to be the `prop` actually does return true or false.

Comment: No, you don't get it: http://api.jquery.com/prop/ Sometime it's true and sometimes it's false, depending on whether the control is checked or not.

Comment: @frenchie: What Ian is saying is true... try it.

Comment: @frenchie I don't understand what you're saying. Have you used `if` statements before?

Comment: Yes, I know that if (a) and if (a === true) are the same but that's not the problem that this question refers to; see the accepted answer, it had to do with an error in Google's extern's definitions.

Comment: @frenchie I completely understand it's not the fix for the bug you've found, but the warning *does* go away when you remove the `=== true`. Again, I know it's not the real fix, but at the same time, `=== true` is unnecessary for this case and most cases. You just seemed to be arguing that it was required until now